# How to download and rename the image file without using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to download an image with the custom file name. The image URL from API call looks like this

`https://develop.api.polyloop.io/form/files/blobs/.../756bb70e4bbe752608753a213fc2c725.png?disposition=attachment`

The downloaded file name is :
`"756bb70e4bbe752608753a213fc2c725.png"` 
Now I want to change the name from this to "name".For this, I tried

```js
const downloadImage = (image: string) => {
    console.log("image1", image);
    FileSaver.saveAs(image, "name");
}
```

The file is downloaded but there is no change in the file name.

Next, I tried axios

```js
axios
    .get(image, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        },
        responseType: "blob",
    })
    .then((response) => {
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "name";
        a.click();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("error", err);
    });
```

Then it downloaded the file with the custom name "name". But I don't want to use axios so is there any other way to achieve the same requirement without using axios. I am new to javascript so Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: You could do this with the build-in [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) functionality

Comment: You should directly set the image download url as the url: `window.open("image url")`. There are limits to the dataUrls which might caught partial image being downloaded if the image is too big. Also, data urls are not performant. Regarding setting the name, if you do `window.open`, browser will ask the user to choose the name. If you want custom name, then do that on the server and send the updated url to the client.